# SecretsManager only pulling part of secret

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, azure-ad-msal, aws-secrets-manager

I am trying to retrieve a fairly long secret, 6,718 characters, but when I run my code it is only retrieving about half of the secret. The get_secret function is the sample code aws gives you in the secret manager. Here is what I'm using to retrieve the secret:

```
import json
import boto3
import base64
import logging
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    logger.info("Inside lambda_handler...")
    
    test = get_secret()
    print(test)
    secretValues = json.loads(test) 
  
    response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {},
        "body": json.loads({
            get_secret()
        })
    }
    return response


def get_secret():
    logger.info("Inside get_secret...")

    secret_name = "demo-ms-graph"
    region_name = "us-east-1"

    # Create a Secrets Manager client
    session = boto3.session.Session()
    client = session.client(
        service_name='secretsmanager',
        region_name=region_name
    )

    # In this sample we only handle the specific exceptions for the 'GetSecretValue' API.
    # See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/apireference/API_GetSecretValue.html
    # We rethrow the exception by default.

    try:
        get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(SecretId=secret_name)
        logger.info("Received Response")
    except ClientError as e:
        if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'DecryptionFailureException':
            # Secrets Manager can't decrypt the protected secret text using the provided KMS key.
            # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            raise e
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InternalServiceErrorException':
            # An error occurred on the server side.
            # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            raise e
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InvalidParameterException':
            # You provided an invalid value for a parameter.
            # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            raise e
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InvalidRequestException':
            # You provided a parameter value that is not valid for the current state of the resource.
            # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            raise e
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'ResourceNotFoundException':
            # We can't find the resource that you asked for.
            # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            raise e
    else:
        # Decrypts secret using the associated KMS key.
        # Depending on whether the secret is a string or binary, one of these fields will be populated.
        if 'SecretString' in get_secret_value_response:
            secret = get_secret_value_response['SecretString']
            return secret
        else:
            logger.info("Inside binary response...")
            decoded_binary_secret = base64.b64decode(get_secret_value_response['SecretBinary'])
            return decoded_binary_secret
```

And this is the result after running the lambda:

```
    Test Event Name
    demo
    
    Response
    {
      "errorMessage": "the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not set",
      "errorType": "TypeError",
      "requestId": "ef5d8634-6246-40ae-99ae-fc7db8dc8b72",
      "stackTrace": [
        "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 20, in lambda_handler\n    \"body\": json.loads({\n",
        "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py\", line 339, in loads\n    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '\n"
      ]
    }
    
REDACTED- SECRET VALUE DISPLAYS ONLY LAST 3,520 CHARACTERS OUT OF 6,718 CHARACTERS TOTAL
 
    [INFO]  2022-08-30T18:22:48.712Z    ef5d8634-6246-40ae-99ae-fc7db8dc8b72    Inside get_secret...
    [INFO]  2022-08-30T18:22:48.835Z    ef5d8634-6246-40ae-99ae-fc7db8dc8b72    Found credentials in environment variables.
    [INFO]  2022-08-30T18:22:49.981Z    ef5d8634-6246-40ae-99ae-fc7db8dc8b72    Received Response
    [ERROR] TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not set
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 20, in lambda_handler
        "body": json.loads({
      File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
        raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, 'END RequestId: ef5d8634-6246-40ae-99ae-fc7db8dc8b72
    REPORT RequestId: ef5d8634-6246-40ae-99ae-fc7db8dc8b72  Duration: 2029.20 ms    Billed Duration: 2030 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 78 MB
```

Is there a limit on the length I can retrieve at once? Is there a better/more efficient way to retrieve a long secret value?

Edit:
Here is the format of the secret I have stored as Plaintext in the secret value.

```
{
    "AccessToken": {
        "ABC123abc": {
            "credential_type": "AccessToken",
            "secret": "ABC123abc",
            "home_account_id": "ABC123abc",
            "environment": "login.microsoftonline.com",
            "client_id": "ABC123abc",
            "target": "Mail.ReadWrite openid profile User.Read email",
            "realm": "common",
            "token_type": "Bearer",
            "cached_at": "166434678289",
            "expires_on": "1663464632790",
            "extended_expires_on": "166346790"
        }
    },
    "Account": {
        "ABC123abc": {
            "home_account_id": "ABC123abc",
            "environment": "login.microsoftonline.com",
            "realm": "common",
            "local_account_id": "ABC123abc",
            "username": "username",
            "authority_type": "MSSTS"
        }
    },
    "IdToken": {
        "ABC123abc": {
            "credential_type": "IdToken",
            "secret": "ABC123abc",
            "home_account_id": "ABC123abc",
            "environment": "login.microsoftonline.com",
            "realm": "common",
            "client_id": "ABC123abc"
        }
    },
    "RefreshToken": {
        "ABC123abc": {
            "credential_type": "RefreshToken",
            "secret": "ABC123abc",
            "home_account_id": "ABC123abc",
            "environment": "login.microsoftonline.com",
            "client_id": "ABC123abc",
            "target": "Mail.ReadWrite openid profile User.Read email",
            "last_modification_time": "16618346349"
        }
    },
    "AppMetadata": {
        "appmetadata-login.microsoftonline.com-ABC123abc": {
            "client_id": "ABC123abc",
            "environment": "login.microsoftonline.com"
        }
    }
}
```

I updated the secret to a simpler value to test the functionality. The secret value is now just 123456 and this was the result:

```
Test Event Name
demo

Response
{
  "errorMessage": "the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not set",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "requestId": "04738981-6707-4d36-8d8a-6b826ebdb5d5",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 21, in lambda_handler\n    \"body\": json.loads({\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py\", line 339, in loads\n    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '\n"
  ]
}

Function Logs
START RequestId: 04738981-6707-4d36-8d8a-6b826ebdb5d5 Version: $LATEST
[INFO]  2022-08-30T19:37:12.956Z    04738981-6707-4d36-8d8a-6b826ebdb5d5    Inside lambda_handler...
[INFO]  2022-08-30T19:37:12.956Z    04738981-6707-4d36-8d8a-6b826ebdb5d5    Inside get_secret...
[INFO]  2022-08-30T19:37:13.076Z    04738981-6707-4d36-8d8a-6b826ebdb5d5    Found credentials in environment variables.
[INFO]  2022-08-30T19:37:13.626Z    04738981-6707-4d36-8d8a-6b826ebdb5d5    Received Response
Heres the secret
{"cache.token":"123456"}
[INFO]  2022-08-30T19:37:13.636Z    04738981-6707-4d36-8d8a-6b826ebdb5d5    Inside get_secret...
[INFO]  2022-08-30T19:37:13.738Z    04738981-6707-4d36-8d8a-6b826ebdb5d5    Found credentials in environment variables.
[INFO]  2022-08-30T19:37:14.384Z    04738981-6707-4d36-8d8a-6b826ebdb5d5    Received Response
[ERROR] TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not set
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 21, in lambda_handler
    "body": json.loads({
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, 'END RequestId: 04738981-6707-4d36-8d8a-6b826ebdb5d5
REPORT RequestId: 04738981-6707-4d36-8d8a-6b826ebdb5d5  Duration: 1439.32 ms    Billed Duration: 1440 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 77 MB

Request ID
04738981-6707-4d36-8d8a-6b826ebdb5d5
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure there is a fully valid JSON string in the stored secret?

Comment: I appended my question with the format in which I have the secret stored in Plaintext in the secret value.

Comment: Can't you just set body to `get_secret()`? Why are you deserialising and then serialising again?

Comment: Actually, it says you have a `set` instead of a `string`  for some reason. I don't think the string is getting truncated, I think there is something else going on. Would really need to see the output of `print(test)` to see what is happening.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary - The get_secret function is the sample code aws gave me when creating the secret. So i'm just using the provided code to retrieve the secret value. Mark B - even when I set the secret value to just "123456" I see the same error.